# In visual studio I am trying to navigate from one page to another by clicking on the button in MainPage using visual c++

Tags: windows-phone

```
void App16::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{

    this->Frame->Navigate(page2::typeid);
}
```

page2 is not being recognized. I don't know what should be the correct syntax in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. add `#include "page2.xaml.h"` at the beginning of the MainPage.xaml.cpp.
2. add `using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;` to enable you use TypeName struct.
3. In button click event, navigate the page by using the following code. `this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(page2::typeid));`

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works...I didn't include page2.xaml.h at the beginning which was creating problem.however using TypeName or not is giving me same page navigation result.

Comment: Using TypeName is recommended in MSDN doc. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx . I can understand many developers focus on the functionality, but I will recommend you create the TypeName struct to avoid any special issue we cannot expect. If the answer do help you, accept it and let others know here is an accepted answer may help them.